# how to list the nodes in docker swarm via api call?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-machine, docker-swarm

I am trying to get the node details of the swarm manager via api call.

```
my question is, is there an api call equivalent to 

docker node ls
```

I tried to get the api details, i searched enough and i cant get it ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the `/info` call? I believe you do not need to look any further. And [here](https://github.com/docker/swarm/issues/735) is a detailed discussion around this particular issue. You will get enough pointer from there I believe.

I am not sure that a fully supported API end point has been added yet. However, as that link suggests you can parse the return of the `/info` call and get a lot of info that you may need.

Does this help?